# How can I cache packages build artefacts for docker build?

Tags: docker, go

A typical go docker pattern is this:

```
# cache modules
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .
RUN make
```

This will create a (cached) layer for downloaded packages before compiling the actual sources. It would be great to not only download but also *compile* the packages before adding the application to further speed up repeated builds.

How would one force-compile all downloaded packages irrespective of the parent application?

Comment: If you find yourself here via search, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68730600/how-to-pre-build-all-required-modules-and-cache-them/68733683#68733683

Answer (score -1):

The goal of using `go mod download` in docker build, is to avoid waiting for the dependencies' sources to be compiled. Since you want to avoid that beahviour, you can replace that line with

```
RUN go get -d -v
```

Comment: I‘m happy not waiting for the download, but I also don‘t want to wait for the compile. Doesn‘t seem -d does that.

Comment: The way you formulated your question was misleading *force-compile all downloaded packages*

So what you really want is to cache the compilation of your application's sources, if no changes were made to your source files, correct?

Comment: No. I want to cache compilation of downloaded packages that my application depends on if such is possible. The idea is that when go.mod doesn't change the packages won't change and hence intermediate compilation results are still usable even if my app's code changes. Maybe such intermediate results (like obj files) don't exist.