# How to pre-build all required modules and cache them

Tags: docker, go

When buliding a Docker image, I know we can add a layer to cache dependencies. But the dependency needs to be built. This step is quite time-consuming, on my machine it takes about 30 seconds to build sqlite3 alone.

I also know I can use `go build github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` to build a specific dependency, but is there any way to pre-build all the dependencies list in `go.mod`?

I found the same question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474679/how-can-i-cache-golang-packages-build-artefacts-for-docker-build), but there is no answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker provides documentation on this exact topic [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/containerize-your-go-developer-environment-part-2/). The suggestion is to structure your `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM --platform=${BUILDPLATFORM} docker.io/golang:1.16.7-alpine AS build
ARG TARGETOS
ARG TARGETARCH
WORKDIR /src
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
COPY go.* .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build \
GOOS=${TARGETOS} GOARCH=${TARGETARCH} go build -o /out/example .

FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /out/example /
```

A lot of that is boilerplate you can remove if you're only building for a single architecture; the parts related to caching are really only:

```
FROM docker.io/golang:1.16.7-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY go.* .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build go build -o /out/example .

FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /out/example /
```

This mounts a cache directory on `/root/.cache/go-build`, which is the default location for the `go` build cache. The first time you build your image it will populate this cache. Subsequent builds will re-use the cached files.

For this to work, you must build with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`, i.e.:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t myimage .
```

Or use `docker buildx`:

```
docker buildx build -t myimage .
```

I have tested this out locally and it seems to work as intended (I have verified that in builds other than the first one, the `go-build` cache directory is populated prior to running `go build`).

Answer (score -1):

This isn't tested within Docker, but should work. It can likely be optimized further, though, or modified to work in more limited build environments

```
RUN go mod download && go list -f '{{ join .Deps "\n" }}' ./... | sort -u | grep -v '<your package import path>' | xargs go build
```

Comment: I have a feeling that this command works, but may I ask which path is <your package import path>?

Comment: @Jannchie: That depends on your package. What package are you building?